# Laravel 6 how to fix error: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist even when i Call paginate method?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-6

i want to show all users in a table and paginate eloquent results.
i call paginate method in user controller like this:

```
$users=User::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
```

and returning view after that like:

```
return view('admin.users.index',compact('users'));
```

and in my view(`index.blade.php`) try to display pagination result using blade like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @if ($users->count()>0)
        @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        </tr>


        @endforeach
        @endif
    </tbody>
</table>

{{$users->links()}}
```

i tried to use `simplePaginate` and getting same error..
by removing  `{{$users->links()}}` works fine. so paginator method works and i get the Paginator object.
this is controller with method called in that route:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users=User::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
        return view('admin.users.index',compact('users'));    
    }
}
```

Comment: plz post more codes about the controller action.

Comment: @TsaiKoga Tnx for Ur attention. ive added full method

Comment: It seems `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` become `collection` somewhere.